# How to delete file containing special characters in Linux?

Tags: linux

I've created a linux bash file in a windows text editor. This file contained commands for moving files to another location under linux.

After i ran this file i discovered that destination files have "\r" symbol in their end. (I guess this is because linux and windows use different line end symbols)

So 'Dir' command shows that i have files like these:
"httpd.conf\r"
while 'ls' shows the same filename as:
"httpd.conf?"

**How do i delete these files ?**

These commands do not work:

```
Rm httpd.conf\r
Rm httpd.conf\\r
rm 'httpd.conf\r'
```

I receive the following error:

rm: cannot lstat `httpd.confr': No such file or directory

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simpler way would be:

```
rm -i httpd.conf?
```

Answer (score 5):

If you get a really chewy filename, you can delete it by inode:
run `ls -il` to get the inode number, then use:
`find -inum <inode number> -exec rm -i {} \;` to delete it.

(Credit to one of my old bookmarks for this one: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/delete-remove-files-with-inode-number.html)

Comment: This should be the marked answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using bash and bash's tab completion is enabled you can use it to complete the filename with the character in question automatically escaped.

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
rm $'httpd.conf\r'
```

or

```
rm 'httpd.conf^M'
```

You obtain `^M` by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>m</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have two files in the same directory:`httpd.conf` and `httpd.conf\r`.

Copy the file(s) you want to keep:

```
$ sudo cp httpd.conf httpd-keep.conf
```

Simply remove **ALL** files that start with httpd.conf:

```
$ sudo rm httpd.conf*
```

Restore the original file:

```
$ sudo mv httpd-keep.conf httpd.conf
```

You need to **BACKUP ALL OTHER FILES** that start with "httpd.conf" if any before executing the `rm` command as shown above.